# Angular Bootstrap Typeahead don't dismiss onclick outside in mobile/tablet

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to hide the typeahead values onclick of outside in mobile, it doesn't dismiss. Below is the html bootstrap typeahead.

```
<input type="text" name="destination"  ng-change="clear()"
                       id="destination"
                       autocomplete="off"

                       ng-model="search.destination"
                       typeahead="item.value as item.label for item in cities($viewValue)"
                       typeahead-on-select="selectTypeaheadItem($item)"
                       typeahead-min-length="{{isDeviceMobileOrTablet ? 0 : 3}}"
                       class="form-control destination"
                       ng-class="{'input-error': destinationEmptyError}"
                       tabindex="1"

                />
```